# Do adverbs derived from iste have a pejorative tone?

Tags: nuance, pronouns, derivation, adverb

I would call the pronoun *iste* a "second person demonstrative pronoun"<sup>1</sup>, meaning roughly "that thing near you".
It can also have a pejorative tone, implying that the speaker does not approve of the thing.
I am not confident in my ability to render idiomatic examples in English; let me know if I need to elaborate on this tone.

Can the adverbs *istuc*, *istic*, and *istinc* derived from *iste* also have such a tone, or do they only mean "to/in/from where you are" without any judgement of the place?

---

<sup>1</sup>
I mean this in the same sense as *hic* is a "first person demonstrative pronoun"; *hic* refers to something close to or possessed by the speaker but not to the speaker.
Similarly, *iste* does not refer to the addressee, but something close to them.
This meaning is not always strong, but quite often it is.

Comment: It's simply a demonstrative pronoun, nothing to do with 'second person'. The adverbs might sometimes carry the implication _that (place, etc.) rather than some other_, but it's not very strong.

Comment: @TomCotton At least [Lewis Elementary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Diste) and the material I studied from indicate that it is indeed second person. [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DI%3Aentry+group%3D77%3Aentry%3Diste) hints at this at I.A.2. Perhaps I should ask a separate question about the second person character of *iste*.

Comment: Those examples only refer the object to a second person. The first instance of your first reference, _tu tibi istas comprimite manus_  (which is a bit strange, having _tu_ followed by a plural imperative),  means 'you keep those hands to yourself', where 'those hands' certainly belong to a second person (_tibi_) but are not themselves being addressed.

Comment: @TomCotton By "second person demonstrative pronoun" I meant a demonstrative pronoun that refers to something possessed by or close to the addressee. I did not mean that that it refers to the addressee. In a same way *hic* refers to something close to the speaker, and I might call it a first person pronoun in a similar fashion. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I see exactly what you are getting at, but the terminology is quite unfamiliar to me! Let's hope that the revised question draws a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

(**Caveat lector**: This "answer" was based on a misreading of the question and addresses the pejorative force of the **pronoun** *istic*, not the adverb. I will leave for now because it is tangentially related.)

---

As a first point, I should mention how exactly *istic* is derived from *iste*: it is *iste* + [*-ce*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dce). This -ce is an "inseparable strengthening demonstrative particle," and is found in other words like *huiusce, tunc, nunc,* or *hocce*. (See also [*Formenlehre der lateinischen sprache*, pg. 211ff](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=F40NAAAAIAAJ), which gives many examples of usage and some irregular formations.)

Given that the -ce is an emphatic form, it seems reasonable to expect it to have the same pejorative nuance when the occasion demands. *Iste* and *istic* occur with enormous frequency in Plautus and Terence, given their use in 2nd person situations--they also appear much more often in letters than in formal addresses or writings. Here are two examples that should demonstrate the point:

> Quod scribis Terentiam de obsignatoribus mei testamenti loqui, primum tibi persuade **me istaec non curare** neque esse quicquam aut parvae curae aut novae loci. (Cicero, *Epistulae ad Atticum* 12.18a)

and (Caelius to Cicero):

> Illud nunc a te peto, si eris, ut spero, otiosus, aliquod ad nos, ut intellegamus nos tibi curae esse, σύνταγμα conscribas. '**qui tibi istuc**' inquis '**in mentem venit**, homini non inepto?' (Cicero, *Epistulae ad Familiares* 8.3.3)

Comment: Thanks! The second example is great, but it seems that the first one has the declinable pronoun *istic* (emphasized *iste*) whereas my question was about the non-declinable adverb *istic* (roughly "there") and its companions. I believe the two words are separate. However, I consider this as good evidence of pejorative nuance; if it is found in a derived pronoun, it makes all the more sense in a derived adverb.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Obviously my reading comprehension skills are lacking :) I'm pretty sure the second *istuc* is a pronoun as well: the *qui* means "why."